# How to put the event on the background and grid to the foreground

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a configuration off FullCalendar like this:

[calendar http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/168785Capture.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/168785Capture.png)

I would like to put the event "Event 1" on the background and the grid on the foreground.

So that the event will be behind the grid.

Comment: You won't break our hearts by showing some code also!!